# How can I change the TTL value of SnappyData table?

Tags: snappydata

How can I change the TTL value for SnappyData table?

For Example: If I create table with TTL = 60 seconds:

```
CREATE TABLE APP.TEST (ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, TTL INTEGER) USING ROW OPTIONS (PARTITION_BY 'ID', EXPIRE '60') ;
```

How can I change the TTL value later if required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Alter table` doesn't support changing properties like `expire` currently. You will need to dump the table into some temp table, delete Test and re-create again.

Comment: Thanks. I will think about that approach